# Mvc6 versioned api actions with custom constraints

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I'm making a versioned api with mvc6 and to do that I want to be able to specify for an action on which api version it should work.

My api route is: `/api/{version}/...` and so I want at a certain action to inspect the `version` route value and to see if this action is available for that version.

I want to be able to specify that as an attribute on the api action, so for example:

```
// This is the base api controller
[Route("api/{version:regex(^v[[0-9]].[[0-9]]$)}/[controller]")]
public abstract class ApiControllerBase { ... }

// This is an action in one of the sub classes
[HttpGet("foo")]
[ApiVersion("0.1", "0.2")] // Here! (this is params string[])
public object Foo()
{
    // return
}

// This is an action in another sub class
[HttpGet("foo")]
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
public object Foo()
{
    // return
}
```

My question is what should `ApiVersion` implement or extend for this to work? I don't believe action filters work as I want because I don't want to return a 404 when this doesn't match because other actions inside other controllers might be able to handle this (Later I might have `HomeController` with common actions and `Home2Controller` with extended actions that work only for `1.0`).

**Note** that I'm not asking for an implementation of `ApiVersionAttribute`, I just need to know what mvc infrastructure I should hook into (action filters, route constraints, ...) that will let me create an attribute that can look into route values and say if this action is a match.

Comment: Why not have separate controllers, perhaps using inheritance? To me having attributes to handle actions seems complicated. And what if an action changes?

Comment: I really just want to have a lot of flexibility when matching which actions apply to what versions. I'm open to other methods if the same flexibility I desire can be achieved. Researching some of those now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It took 4 hours analyzing the mvc6 source but it was worth it. I solved this using an action attribute implementing `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ActionConstraints.IActionConstraint`.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true)]
public class ApiVersionAttribute : Attribute, IActionConstraint
{
    public ApiVersionAttribute(string version)
    {
        Version = version;
    }

    public string Version { get; }

    public int Order => 0;

    public bool Accept(ActionConstraintContext context)
    {
        var routeData = context.RouteContext.RouteData;
        // return ...
    }
}
```

And then on a certain action:

```
[HttpGet("foo")]
[ApiVersion("0.1")]
public object Foo()
{
    // return ...
}
```